# how do I add asynchronous switching between related collections C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I have project where I need to gather files from a database by id, zip those files up, upload zipped file to third party web service, and do something with the response.  I'm using the Parallel.ForEach to try and accomplish this, but I'm having trouble getting this to run asynchonously, and I'm not even sure that this is the best way to do this. Is there a way to run this asynchronously, and more efficiently?

```
    public async Task<string> UploadZip(string courseID)
    {
         string result = string.empty;
         ids = courseID.Split(',').ToList();

         ConcurrentStack<string> zipPaths  = new ConcurrentStack<string>();

        Parallel.ForEach(ids, (id) =>
         {
             files = rep.GetFiles(id); 
            ZipFiles zf = new ZipFile(files);       
            zipPaths.Push(zf.ZipFilePath);
             try
             {
                 while (zipPaths.Count > 0)
                 {
                     FileHolder fh;
                     if (fileHolder.TryPop(out fh))
                     {

                             FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fh.EndPoint);

                             if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
                             {
                                 // string fileName = Path.GetFileName(path); 
                                result = CallService(zf.PathToZip);
                                 DoSomethingElse oSomethingElse = new DoSomethingElse(result, id, version);
                             }                             

                     }
                 }
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                 System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Concat("HomeController line 123","error ",ex.Message, DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay));
             }
             ITermExtractorContent result = new TermExtractorContent();

         });


        return output;
    }

     private static async Task<string> CallService(string pathToZip)
        {

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
               //headers for client
                try
                {
                    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                    {
                        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                        {
                            using (var fileContent = new StreamContent(stream))
                            {
                                fileContent.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + Path.GetFileName(path) + "\"");
                                content.Add(fileContent, "file", Path.GetFileName(pathToZip));
                                using (
                                   var message =
                                       await client.PostAsync(baseEndpoint, content))
                                {
                                    output = await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }//end using

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    log(ex);
                }

            }// using (var client = new HttpClient())
            return output;
        }
```

Comment: There is no reason to use Async for CPU bound operations.  Async is basically a way to prevent a thread from doing nothing while waiting on an external source.  Your code is doing a lot of work, exactly what a thread is for.

Comment: I see your first method doesn't have any await keyword; which means your code isn't really asynchronous. You must be getting a compiler warning stating the same.

Comment: @ErikPhilips But I want to have two processes 1.one for the getting files and zipping them 2. and the other to take zipped files, upload, wait for a response. Unless I'm wrong 1 should take less time than 2-hence the need for two threads essentially.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel That is correct. I'm pretty new to TPL in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason why I can see this needing to be async is to prevent from blocking a UI thread.  I'm not sure what `DoSomethingElse()` does (Is this the method you are trying to run concurrently?) and how you use the result variable as a parameter but I feel that the above line `result = CallService(zf.PathToZip);` should be `result = await CallService(zf.PathToZip);`  As the current function is marked as async it will signal the compiler to create a callback to execute when the task has returned and will resume execution there.  When your program hits that method, it will not continue to execute until it is returned.  Other threads (like the one that called the async method) will continue to execute.  To call you `UploadZip()` method it would be used something like:

```
public void DoThings()
{
    UploadZip("MyString");
    DoSomethingElseConcurrently();
}
```

Please also bear in mind thread safety (race conditions, deadlocking etc) as this is asynchronous programming.  There are some minor things when using the TPL here as you may find yourself nesting async method calls (like you are doing here).  Outer async calls can not use the `.Result()` method as it blocks that thread.  The inner async thread will try to return to that method that called it and thus entering into a deadlock.

Comment: I'm using a progress bar in UI so I for sure don't want to block that.